# Show that $(\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z})/[\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}]\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, free-product

Im trying to show that
$$(\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z)}/[\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}]\cong \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$$
and my first thought was to use the first isomorphism theorem. I've been trying to use the homomorphism
$$\phi:\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$$ defined by
$$\phi(a^{n_1}b^{m_1}\cdots a^{n_k}b^{m_k})=(a^{n_1}\cdots a^{n_k},b^{m_1}\cdots b^{m_k})$$ Where we are considering $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ to be the free product of two infinite cyclic groups generated by a and b respectively. I have shown that this is a homomorphism and is surjective, but i am really struggling to show that the commutator is the kernel. I have that the commutator is contained in the kernel but i cannot show the other containment. I am beginning to suspect that it is in fact not equal to the kernel, but if that is the case I am stumped on how to proceed. I was hoping someone would be able to shine some light on the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Let $F_2 = \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$, and let $F_2^{ab} = F_2/[F_2, F_2]$ denote its abelianization. For any abelian group $A$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{Hom}(F_2^{ab}, A) = \operatorname{Hom}(F_2, A) = A\oplus A,
\end{equation*}
since $F_2$ is a free group of rank $2$. But $F_2^{ab}$ is a finitely-generated abelian group and thus must be of the form $\mathbb{Z}^n \oplus A_0$ for some integer $n\geq 0$ and some finite abelian group $A_0$, and it follows quickly that $F_2^{ab}$ must be $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: You don't need to invoke the classification of fg groups. Since $\operatorname{Hom}(F_2^{ab}, A)= \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb Z^2 , A)$ it follows that $F_2^{ab}=\mathbb Z^2$

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez: Because $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is free in the category of abelian groups? OK, but I'm not sure that's actually simpler than using the classification of f.g. abelian groups.

Comment: Well, freeness of $\mathbb Z^2$ is simpler than the classification of f.g. groups, but no, this is just an instance of Yoneda's lemma: Suppose $B$, $C$ are abelian groups and you have a homomorphism $f:B \to C$ (which you have in this case naturally: $F_2^{ab} \to \mathbb Z^2$). Then $f$ is an isomorphism if and only if the induced map $f^* : \text{Hom}(C,A) \to \text{Hom}(B,A)$ is an isomorphism for all $A$. The proof of this fact is very simple.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were claiming that $\operatorname{Hom}(A, G) = \operatorname{Hom}(B, G)$ for all abelian $G$ implies that $A$ and $B$ (abelian groups) are isomorphic. If the isomorphism is natural--- as it here, being induced from abelianization--- then it's indeed just literally the Yoneda lemma for the category of abelian groups.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring out something using the first isomorphism theorem like I initially wanted to. Using the same homomorphism defined in my question, I was able to show that $[\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}]=\ker(\phi)$. I did this using a lemma:

An element in $w\in\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$, where
$$w=a^{n_1}b^{m_1}\cdots a^{n_k}b^{m_k}$$ is also an element of $[\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}]$ if and only if
$$n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_k=0\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,m_1+m_2+\cdots+m_k=0$$
This lemma was fairly easy to prove using induction on the lengths of words where, to apply the induction step, you must multiply by some commutators to reduce the word length. Then with this tool it is easy enough to show that given some arbitrary $x\in \ker(\phi)$, we must have $x$ satisfying the right hand side of that iff and thus $\ker(\phi)=[\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}]$. Then the first isomorphism theorem applies and yields the final result.